# Writing a macro

Tags: macros

I'm mostly new to programming and so I have come here for some help.

Recently, at work, the program that we have used for years has drastically changed and all of our old file types are no longer supported. This has left us completely out in the cold as to how we can access our old files without using the older software. With that being said, here is my problem with macros that I'm in need of help:

I need to be able to open a file in a specific program, copy all the text in the file, paste the text into a new notepad document and then save the notepad file with file's original name as a simple text document. I need to do this to an entire folder (and eventually folders within a folder but that can wait for now)

If I need to clarify anything let me know. Like I said, I'm new to this stuff and I'd appreciate any tips you guys could give me.

Comment: You're probably going to have to tell us the program name for some investigation (unless it's some sort of bespoke software). There's possibilities with using `SendKeys` and such, that might work.

Comment: Well I work with a CNC program called BobCAD, and more specifically it's companion Predator CNC Editor. If anyone is familiar with G-codes they should know what I mean. Does that help any?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Notepad, I'll assume that you are working in Windows.  In that case, you're probably best off writing it in PowerScript.   I don't have the skills for that, but if you add "Windows" and "PowerScript" to the tags, you may have a better chance of find someone sho does.   (You may want to try this question over at SuperUser)

Comment: I will. Thanks for the help. Also, apparently I need a reputation of at least 15 to add a new tag such as PowerScript. *shrug* Oh well.